# Trouble deleting mesh parts from sculpting -From symmetric View

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, sculpting, dynamic-topology

So I am quite familiar to Blender but I am coming across this very annoying part in sculpting mode in Blender. I did in fact have dyntopo on so you all know and was increasing from the original mesh until I increased something and decided I didn't want it. I tried to decrease it but I couldn't as it still has some sort of left over and I can't remove it.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

Now, how can I remove this, I really need to remove it or it will just be such a nuisance and I just don't want start over from the my last history point (I create certain history saves just in case I mess something up big.), as I didn't do it in a while.

I should mention I am making a humanoid so I can't just go to edit mode and delete those vertices as it won't be symmetric if I did because I would have to try to get it just right and that will take way too long.

So how would I remove this properly with keep symmetric on both sides and such?

**Update 1:**
I really still need help, like badly. I cannot continue my work until I know how to delete it. I really don't wanna start all over.

**Update 2:**
I am going to upload my blend file. I tried using blender exchange personally file hoster, but the upload bar will not budge so I used mediafire instead. Hopefully that is alright. I did use the same image for most however, just a quick update on that so no one gets misleaded.

So when ever you download it, try to sculpt the arms down and see what happens first. So you can get a better picture.
[image]

**Conclusion [Solved]:**
I've got an answer I have been looking for so I've edited the title and added a tag to help with others who may have the same problem I did.
I believe to well understand the answer, you should know blender quite a bit to get what the answer means.

Comment: Don't see any pinching part opening your file... where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the vertices in Edit Mode and use Symmetrize function to make identical changes on the other size.

Select the pinching vertices and delete them. Fix the hole that was left behind. Select all <kbd>a</kbd> and under Mesh select Symmetrize. In your model x asix is up so you need to use Symmetrize direction +Z to -Z to make the other arm identical.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned but when I do click Symmetrize under Mesh, it just deletes the whole body and just leaves the head.

Comment: It really shouldn't do that. Could you share the .blend file so it can be inspected better?

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow. I just closed up Blender for tonight. It is 1:25 AM for me (Just in case you seem to be inside another timezone.) You promise to check back tomorrow to further aid me?

Comment: Yeah I'm in Europe and it's early morning here. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Well, alright. So I uploaded it now. I used media fire as I got a bit impatient at the uploading on the Blend-exchange personal upload cloud as it wasn't budging.

Comment: I checked your model and you need to remove the vertices from other arm and fix the hole that was left. Then use symmetrize with direction +z to -z. This worked for me in your model.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Took me a while to fill out the hold thing with grids. Only to realize it doesn't really matter if it is solid or not. (Grid fill just bulges it out in a uncomfortable way for me.)
Thanks for your help, I really appreciated it, that was driving me crazy.

Comment: One more thing, I would like to know (A bit off topic) any title suggestion changes. I would love to change it to a title people can find easily if they have the same problem as me in the future. I know a bit off-topic but my title isn't that creative.

Comment: Maybe "How to fix pinching vertices while sculpting"?

Comment: Needs to be more universal, so I got a title that might work.